# Android NDK: aborting .stop

Tags: android, android-ndk

I imported telegram source from GitHub in Android Studio. When I try to debug the project, I got following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:TMessagesProj:generateArmv7DebugSources,:TMessagesProj:generateArmv7DebugAndroidTestSources]
/Users/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk
Error:(45) *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':TMessagesProj'.
> executing external native build for ndkBuild /Users/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/jni/Android.mk
```

My Android Studio version is 1.5.1, and gradle version is 2.3.0. Target SDK is 25 and system is Mac.

Build.gradle file is as:

```
externalNativeBuild {
       ndkBuild {
            arguments "NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk", "APP_PLATFORM:=android-14"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

and Prebuilt_library.mk file is as follow:

```
ifndef prebuilt
$(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE): LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file)
$(call __ndk_info,Check that $(prebuilt_path) exists, or that its path is correct)
$(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
endif
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

LOCAL_MODULE    := avutil 

ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/armv7-a/libavutil.a
else
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/armv5te/libavutil.a
else
    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./ffmpeg/i686/libavutil.a
    endif
endif
endif

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

I do not have any idea how to handle this problem.

Comment: Include your Android.mk

Comment: @DanAlbert can you explain more. You ask me to show android.mk contains here? or including this file in my build.gradle?

Comment: Include it here.

Comment: @DanAlbert you can find android.mk above.

Comment: Try running these commands in the terminal from your `app` directory to get more details. `gradlew build --info`, `gradlew build --stacktrace`, `gradlew build --debug`. One of those should tell you exactly which command is causing the build to fail.